# Prove the infimum of monotone decreasing set equals its limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose that the sequence (sn) is monotone decreasing, in other words s1 ≥ s2 ≥ .... 
In addition suppose (sn) converges to s ∈ R.
With these assumptions, prove that the set E = {s1, s2, ...} has an infimum and that inf E = s.

Answer (score 5):

Since $E$ is bounded below by $s$, $Inf(E) = a$ exists. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, there exists $N$  with $s_N < a + \epsilon$, and since $(s_n)$ is a decreasing sequence, $s_N \geq s_n$ for all $n \geq N$, so: $s_n \le s_N < a + \epsilon$, but it is already true that: $s_n \ge a > a - \epsilon$ for all $n$. Thus: for all $n \geq N$, $a - \epsilon < s_n < a + \epsilon$ or $|s_n - a| < \epsilon$, showing that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = a$. so $a = s$

Comment: Thanks s lot!!! This method helps! It proceeds from a different method from mine.

Comment: This is a really great answer and helped a lot of people I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Proceed as follows.

Certainly, $s$ is a lower bound.  Assume, however, that $s$ is not the greatest lower bound.  Instead, perhaps there exists a larger one, say $s+ \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.

Can you arrive at a contradiction?  (Apply the definition of convergence).

Comment: Initially I proceed by showing s is greater than a lower bound of s_n, but I was stuck at showing s is a lower bound. I used triangle inequality to |s and get |s|<|Sn|. But if I want to show s is a lower bound, there should not be the absolute value.